# Python recursive method calls with super

Tags: python, super

I am working with a library that relies on a recursive method call:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None

    def f(self):
        if not self.foo:
            print("Hello")
            self.foo = 100
            self.f()
```

I would like to override the method f() while using the original implementation:

```
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        super(B, self).f()
        print("World")
```

This way, I hope to get:

```
Hello
World
```

Instead, I see:

```
Hello
World
World
```

I understand this is because the original code in class A calls self.f(), which finds B.self.

**Question:** What is the most Pythonic way to have "super(B, self).f()" treat self as class A, call A.f() recursively, and then return to B.f() to print "World?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can see this work is for `A.f()` to not use `self.f()` but to use `A.f(self)` instead.

A better design is for `A.f()` to delegate the recursive call to a separate method:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None

    def f(self):
        self._f_recursive()

    def _f_recursive(self):
        if not self.foo:
            print("Hello")
            self.foo = 100
            self._f_recursive()
```

If your only option lies in `B`, then apart from *don't override `f()`* then, is to lie about the class, temporarily. **This is not Pythonic or recommended** but it'll work:

```
class B(A):
    def f(self):
        try:
            self.__class__, cls = A, self.__class__
            A.f(self)
        finally:
            self.__class__ = cls
        print("World")
```

To be clear about this: this is not thread-safe nor the proper way to deal with this.

Comment: I agree the better design is to change the implementation in A. In this case, there are a couple of reasons I cannot change A; was hoping to find something that can still work by only changing B. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @Max: Added the hackish route: lie about `self`'s class.

Comment: You're right, that's pretty terrible. Maybe I will press for the better option here... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hardly seems worth quibbling over something that's already so nasty, but shouldn't you save and restore the original value of `__class__`, in case it's not initially `B`? :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: indeed.